# SharedPreferences retreival error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Well after researching this fairly thorough.. i've got my code for it. All the resources ive seen show that my code syntax is correct however i'm getting force quit issues with my app.. Here is my current code:

```
package com.MonatecSolutions.SafeN_Secure;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by cchance on 6/24/2014.
 */
public class settingActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txt_nameval;
    EditText txt_delayval;
    Button btn_save;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_settings);

        // Grab the preferences
        final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0); // Made final for the onClickListener

        txt_nameval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_myName);
        txt_delayval = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_delay);
        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        // Setting the text from the preferences
        String myName = preferences.getString("myName", "");
        int myDelay = preferences.getInt("delay", 60);
        txt_nameval.setText(myName);
        txt_delayval.setText(myDelay);

        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Saving the settings and returning to the main screen
                preferences.edit().putString("myName", txt_nameval.getText().toString()).commit();
                preferences.edit().putInt("delay", Integer.parseInt(txt_delayval.getText().toString())).commit();
                startActivity(new Intent(settingActivity.this, MyActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From logcat im getting this:

```
06-24 15:12:50.679    1852-1852/com.MonatecSolutions.SafeN_Secure E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.MonatecSolutions.SafeN_Secure, PID: 1852
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.MonatecSolutions.SafeN_Secure/com.MonatecSolutions.SafeN_Secure.settingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:173)
        at com.MonatecSolutions.SafeN_Secure.settingActivity.<init>(settingActivity.java:21)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope someone can shed some light on this for me. I come from a C# background so i may be doing something that i know i can do in C# but not realizing that it cant be done in Java.

Comment: No @jungleboy This is how i had it before, but due to Tyler Olson's possible answer i moved it to the outer scope so that it didn't need the final

Comment: Did you register `Activity` in `manifest` file?

Comment: yes the activity is registered. This issue only started happening after the inclusion of the SharedPrefferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `SharedPreferences` creation code inside `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_settings);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);

    //Other stuffs here
}
```

**[Edit1]**
Replace `Integer` with `int` in the following statement:

```
Integer myDelay = preferences.getInt("delay", 60);
```

**[Edit2]**
Did you register `Activity` in `manifest` file?

**[Edit3]**
The culprit is this statement:

```
 txt_delayval.setText(myDelay);
```

Replace it with:

```
txt_delayval.setText("" + myDelay);
```

Comment: yes the activity is registered. This issue only started happening after the inclusion of the SharedPrefferences

Comment: wow... so the override  public final void setText(int resid) absolutly is bogus. You got it! I just dont get how the override failed.. Final fix: The integer has to be case (either explicitly or implicitly) into a string. Good Find!

Comment: @ClintChance, the `resid` which it shows is the id of a resource(like `TextView`). You cannot simply pass an integer value which does not map to a resource.

Comment: Which would explain why it was looking for a resource. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in an Activity, you shouldn't need to define Preference Manager as it gets preferences from the Context. I've never used 'final' when creating a SharedPreferences variable. I would also use a string and number for the parameters as shown below:
**EDIT:** Define preferences before calling functions

```
public class settingActivity extends Activity {
TextView txt_nameval;
EditText txt_delayval;
Button btn_save;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
protected SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_settings);
    preferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

There's a pretty good example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: So i modified the code, however the front end issue is still arising, however logcat has something new to say.

Comment: Could you tell me what the error is? And where about it's occurring?

Comment: The error is occuring when i enter the activity. Issue is documented in logcat, however i'm not skilled enough to fully read it just yet (I just got to be able to read trace stacks from C# :) )

Comment: Try the most recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

// save

void save()
{

```
SharedPreferences shfObject=getSharedPreferences("savefile",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


     SharedPreferences.Editor  shfEditorObject=shfObject.edit();

     shfEditorObject.putInt("score", highscore);
```

}

//load

void load()
{

```
        SharedPreferences shfObject=getSharedPreferences("savefile",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        highscore=shfObject.getInt("score", highscore);
```

}

Comment: Im not sure how setting objects for the load and save events would help here. I will give it a shot and let you know however.